# How to upload to S3 bucket taking a photo with the iOS Camera

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, uiimageview

I am trying to use the `AWS S3 bucket` to store user photos from when they have taken them from their phones. I right now have my code set up to the point where the user is able to take a photo of something and have that show up on the `UIImageView`.

The issue I am encountering is that I have no clue how to store it on the S3 bucket, I have code right now that is able to store a specified photo the bucket, but not really code that is able to store a photo that is taken from the camera.

**Take Photo code**

```swift
    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            takenPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            takenPhoto.image = pickedImage
            print(takenPhoto.image = pickedImage)
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

**AWS S3 Bucket Code**

```swift
    @IBAction func uploadFile(_ sender: Any) {
        uploadFile(with: "eartj", type: ".jpeg")

    }


    func uploadFile(with resource: String, type: String){
        let key = "\(resource),\(type)"
        let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: type)!
        let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)

        let request = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!

        request.bucket = "wuuurktest"
        request.key = key
        request.body = imageUrl
        request.acl = .publicReadWrite

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

        transferManager.upload(request).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread()) { (task) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                print(error)

            }

            if task.result != nil {
                print("Uploaded File")

            }

            return nil

        }

    }
```

Link to the guide I am using to create the file upload

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMgApUhg7ic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answers are outdated and too complicated. I was struggling with the same problem and finally found a solution.

This works best for me and works on **Swift 5**.

First of all, let's update the function to upload images to `AWS`.

```
func uploadToS3(url: URL) {
    let fileArr = url.path.components(separatedBy: "/") // Path will be too long, so you have to separate the elements by / and store in an array
    let key = fileArr.last // We get the last element of the array which in our case will be the image (my-image.jpg)
    let localImageUrl = url
    
    let request = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    request.bucket = bucketName
    request.key = key
    request.body = localImageUrl
    request.acl = .publicReadWrite
    
    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(request).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread()) { (task) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print(error)
        }
        if task.result != nil {
            print("Uploaded \(key)")
            let contentUrl = self.s3Url.appendingPathComponent(bucketName).appendingPathComponent(key!)
            self.contentUrl = contentUrl
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

In this block of code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        takenPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        takenPhoto.image = pickedImage
        print(takenPhoto.image = pickedImage)
        // Add here:
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("my-image", isDirectory: false)
            .appendingPathExtension("jpg") /* here we are naming the image 'my-image' and it will be 'jpg', if you want you can add a counter to increase the number each time you upload an image, and you make something like this: "my-image-\(counter)"*/

        // Then write to disk
        if let data = pickedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: url)
                uploadToS3(url: url) //Call the updated function to store to AWS bucket
            } catch {
                print("Handle the error, i.e. disk can be full")
            }
        }
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

With this implementation, the image will be uploaded immediately to the server once you select the image from the library.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to store the picked image in your app's document directory as a temporary file. As soon as your image is picked, save it to the document directory using the below function.

```
func saveFileToDocumentDirectory(file: Data, fileExtension: String, folderName: String) -> URL? {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
    let stringOfDateTimeStamp = formatter.string(from: Date())
    print("Date time stamp String: \(stringOfDateTimeStamp)")

    let directoryPath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(folderName)/")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directoryPath) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: directoryPath), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    let filename = "/\(stringOfDateTimeStamp)_\(fileExtension)"
    let customPath = "\(folderName)\(filename)"
    let filepath = directoryPath+filename
    print("FilePATH: \(filepath)")
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filepath)
    do {
        try file.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
        print("CustomPAth:\(customPath)")
        print(String.init("\(directoryPath)\(filename)"))
        return url

    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("file cant not be save at path \(filepath), with error : \(error)");
        return nil
    }
}
```

This will return a URL and you can then use the below function to upload that file to your S3 bucket.

```
func uploadToS3(url: URL, contentType: String, fileExtension: String){
    SwiftLoader.show(title: "Uploading File", animated: true)
    let accessKey = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
    let secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let remoteName = "IMG_\(UUID().uuidString)"+".\(fileExtension)"
    let S3BucketName = "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    uploadRequest.body = url
    uploadRequest.key = remoteName
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = contentType
    uploadRequest.acl = .publicRead

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("An error occurred while Uploading your file, try again.")
                SwiftLoader.hide()
            }
        }
        if task.result != nil {
            let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
            let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
            print("Uploaded to:\(String(describing: publicURL))")
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Don't forget to delete your temporary file once your upload is successful.

Comment: Is there a way to save it without saving it temporarily after taking the photo with the camera?

Comment: There might be, I cant tell you for sure. But I tried a lot of different methods, and this worked perfectly for me. In my case i had multiple types of files like Audio, Video, Images & Document files. So my approach here is more generalized. I call this same function to upload any file type to S3. Based on my research i feel storing it temporarily is necessary, as you are passing the URL of the file to S3 as the `body`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using `TransferUtility`:-

```
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
import AWSS3

typealias progressBlock = (_ progress: Double) -> Void
typealias completionBlock = (_ response: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void


//using Utility upload expression
func uploadImage(with image: URL, key: String?, progress: progressBlock?, completion: completionBlock?) {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = { (task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, awsProgress: Progress) -> Void in
        //print(awsProgress.fractionCompleted)
        guard let uploadProgress = progress else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uploadProgress(awsProgress.fractionCompleted)
        }
    }
    
    expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl")
    expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")
    
    
    // Completion block
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if error == nil {
                let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
                let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(AWS.bucketName).appendingPathComponent(key!)
                print("Uploaded to:\(String(describing: publicURL))")
                if let completionBlock = completion {
                    completionBlock(publicURL?.absoluteString, nil)
                }
            } else {
                if let completionBlock = completion {
                    completionBlock(nil, error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    // Start uploading using AWSS3TransferUtility
    let awsTransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    
    awsTransferUtility.uploadFile(
        image as URL,
        bucket: AWS.bucketName, //Make sure you write the correct bucket name here
        key: key!, //"private/{user_identity_id}/my-picture.png"
        contentType: "image/png",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
            
            if let error = task.error {
                print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                
            }
            if let _ = task.result {
                // your uploadTask
                print("Starting upload...")
            }
            
            return nil
        })
    
}
```

Two parameters I am passing:-

`image: URL` and `key: String?`

Here is how I get image and image name (key):-

```
//setting temp name for upload // I am using a random string here
let imageName = "\(CommonMethod.randomString(length: 6))" + ".png"
            
//settings temp location for image
let tempDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
guard let localUrlPath = image!.save(at: tempDirectoryUrl) else { return } 
//URL
print(localUrlPath)
```

Happy coding!